# Transforming an image to gray-scale in Java

Tags: java, image-processing

I want to display a gray scale image (16 bits per pixel). So far, I have this:

```
DataInputStream aFile = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("filename.raw"));
BufferedImage aBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(2000, 2000, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY);
WritableRaster aRaster = aBufferedImage.getRaster();
byte[] aRow = new byte[2000*2];
aFile.readFully(aRow, 0, 2000*2);
```

Now, my question is that how do I set the 16-bit intensity values from `aRow` to `aBufferedImage`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on http://java.itags.org/java-tech/17212/, you could convert your byte array into an int or double array (to have one array cell per pixel), and then use `WritableRaster.setSamples()` or `WritableRaster.setPixels()`. To avoid doing the byte-to-ushort conversion by yourself, you can use `DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort()`.